# Invalid Regex Byte Sequence

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to compile/install libX11, but am having trouble in the `nls` subdirectory. Make is dying on the following command:

```
/usr/bin/cpp  -DWCHAR32=1 < ./locale.alias.pre | sed \
    -e '/^#  *[0-9][0-9]*  *.*$/d' \
    -e '/^#line  *[0-9][0-9]*  *.*$/d' \
    -e '/^[     ]*XCOMM$/s/XCOMM/#/' \
    -e '/^[     ]*XCOMM[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/s/XCOMM/#/' \
    -e '/^[     ]*XHASH/s/XHASH/#/' -e '/\@\@$/s/\@\@$/\\/' > locale.alias.l1
```

The error message is `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`. Can anyone point out to me where the invalid byte sequence is? Thanks.

Comment: This could be either something being "emitted" by your `cpp` and being passed into `sed` OR there is something wrong with the `sed -e '/...'` cmds. The simplest thing is to comment out all but 1 `-e /.../` cmd, and determine if any of these really have problems. It would also help if you add tags to your question to show what OS your are building in, what ver of `cpp` and `sed`. Finally, while it shouldn't cause a problem even if true, if you copy/pasted the `/^[     ]` bits into that code, manually edit them to be sure it is really a space char and a tab char inside the `[ .. ]` sq brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, `sed` was complaining about UTF-8 characters (`å`, `ç`, et al) in a non-UTF8 file. Removing the lines with those characters fixed the problem.